# Vim: set alternate-file based on current file name

Tags: vim

When I code with unit tests, usually I need to be able to switch to the unit test file quickly. Usually, there is a pattern that names of source code files and unit test files are following, e.g.

```
/common-path-1/lib/common-path-2/source.ext
/common-path-2/unittests/common-path-2/tests_source.ext
```

How do I do this in Vim?

Answer (score 2):

Use [a.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31). It was designed with the `*.c/*.h` alternate in mind but it shouldn't be that difficult to adapt it to your needs.